# How to know when a generalized additive model need to be used for binary data?

Tags: logistic, linear, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

When we have response variable that is of binary type and our interest is to know how probability is associated with covariates then we use logistic regression.

But I specifically want to know about logistic **generalized additive models** (gam).

Suppose, I have a data with binary response. How can I know whether here I need a **linear** or a **gam** **logistic**?

As for other data type, I can plot scatter plot of response vs covariate and if I see nonlinear pattern I can use gam. But for binary response, I can not have that choice.

(Adding `mgcv` tag as anyone using it may have understanding on this issue).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use a GAM vs GLM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380426/when-to-use-a-gam-vs-glm)

Comment: (In short: We never do know beforehand if there is non-linearity in how a predictor affects our outcome. That is true for all modelling endeavours unless we have intricate knowledge about the system's dynamics.)

Comment: @TanIa What about that does not answer your question? At a glance, it sure looks like a duplicate. Is the question not the same as yours (and, if so, why)? Is the question the same but the answer inadequate?

Comment: @Dave One could interpret the question as asking "how can I test statistically if I need a smooth over a linear function?", which is what I answer below (and which isn't addressed at the other Q&A). But I only interpreted the question that way because I get asked this question a lot when teaching GAM - it's not at all clear from the Q if this is what is being asked; "how can I know..." isn't very precise/clear.

Answer (score 3):

A logistic GLM will fit *linear* functions of covariates on the scale of the link function  (linear predictor), whereas a GAM would fit smooth functions on this scale. If you aren't sure if you need a GAM, you could just fit the GAM, check if the size of the basis expansion for each smooth was sufficiently large (via `k.check()` or `gam.check()`), and rely on the smoothing parameters to shrink away unnecessary wiggliness.

If you want a formal test for the necessity or otherwise of the wiggly bits of the smooth over a purely linear effect, you can do this with a modification to the null space for the default thin plate spline basis.

```r
# pseudo code
m <- gam(y ~ x + s(x, m = c(2, 0), bs = "tp"),
         data = foo, method = "REML", family = binomial())
```

where we fit a linear term in `x` plus a smooth function of `x`, but we have modified the basis for the smooth so that it no longer includes linear functions in the span of the basis. This modification is done by `m = c(2, 0)`, which indicates we want the usual second order derivative penalty but with a 0 size null space (the span of functions that aren't affected by the penalty because they have 0 second derivative). With this specification, the output from `summary()` will give a test for the necessity of the wiggliness provided by the smooth over the linear effect estimated by the linear term.

Comment: The assumptions of the two methods are very different; it makes no sense to assume that the estimated function(s) are smooth *and* that the functions are piecewise constant. What does "observed linear predictor" mean? The linear predictor is not observed, it is a linear combination of terms, the constants therefor having been *estimated* from the observed data. If you mean't can we predict from the model for the observed data on the scale of the linear predictor, then yes `predict(m, type = "link")`, which is the default.